Drawbacks of using ETW for packet capture instead of an NDIS LWF or WFP driver?
Assume we want to capture IPv4 and IPv6 packets and do deep packet scans on them. I came to notice that it is also possible to capture packets using the Microsoft-Windows-NDIS-PacketCapture ETW provider.
Some example projects that are doing this:
https://github.com/packetzero/etwrealtime
https://github.com/egtra/ndiscap-packet
If our goal is to do deep packet inspection on IPv4 and IPv6 packets only, and also we are OK with the deep packet inspection to be asynchronous (No need to block the packet while doing the scan), Is there any drawback of using this provider to do packet inspection instead of using an NDIS LWF or WFP driver?

In general, we'd prefer that you use the OS's built-in packet capture, instead of writing your own driver. If the built-in capture works for you, go ahead and use it.
One drawback of the Microsoft-Windows-NDIS-PacketCapture provider is that you don't necessarily control when it starts or stops, and you don't necessarily control the packet filter. There's only a single global capture session, and some other app on the system can mess with your session. (Anything your app can do, their app can do.) But if the system is under your full control, like a lab system, then you can just avoid running anything that conflicts with your use of the built-in capture provider.

One last question: Does this provider also emit packets that are generated from kernel-mode drivers as well? (Packets created and sent directly from kernel-mode). Basically is there any chance we miss any IPv4/IPv6 packet when using this provider vs using an NDIS LWF or WFP?

Yes, in nearly all cases. Typically a kernel driver that behaves like an application would be an NDIS protocol driver or WSK client. Those are always captured by ndiscap. The only traffic that ndiscap can't see is that from a specialty driver stack that doesn't use NDIS (like dpdk) or an NDIS LWF that deliberately bends the rules to evade ndiscap (I'm not aware of any of these, except a few instances of malware. And chasing those is really tricky.)
